# How to lock web folder?

Tags: python, django, apache, web, localhost

I am developing a web django application which I am planning to sell , When I put the same in the client machine I would like to lock the django folder so that no one see or copy the content(code) , they should be able to access the app only through the browser.

Comment: Any reason not to use plain old `.htaccess`? Take a look at this http://community.webfaction.com/questions/907/using-same-htaccess-file-to-lock-development-site-open-production-site-and-treat-different-groups-differently

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what access your customer(s) have to the "client machine." If it's their machine and/or they have root access, there's nothing you can do to prevent them from accessing the source folder. However, you could ship only the .pyc files of your source. They still be able to copy/deploy the files somewhere else if they wanted, but they wouldn't be able to view the actual source.

If they have limited access to the machine (non-root user), then you just need to make sure your permissions on the source directory are set to only allow access to accounts that need it (e.g., the web server user).

If they don't have an account to the machine, then you don't need to do anything: they won't be able to view or copy your source.